# VB.NET Dealing with SQL Nulls and SqlString.Null

Tags: sql, vb.net

I would like to test SQL output parameters for NULL values. What I have realised is that SQLString.NULL is not equal to DBNull.Value. My question is, is there a more general way of checking a parameter for null values?

Ideally I do not want to have to check each parameter based on their SQL type, e.g. integer parameters SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
.ExecuteStoredProcedure("spGetClientDetails")

If CInt(.Parameters("@return_val").Value) = 0 Then

If myParams(1).SqlValue.Equals(SqlTypes.SqlString.Null) Or myParams(1).SqlValue.Equals(System.DBNull.Value) Then
    Claimants = ""
Else...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Value` instead of `SqlValue`, you'll get regular .NET types instead of an `SqlType`.  When the database returns `NULL`, `Value` will be set to `DBNull.Value`.

A concise way to check for `DBNull.Value` is `TryCast`:

```
Dim Claimants As String = TryCast(myParams(1).Value, String)
```

This will set `Claimants` to `Nothing` if `myParams(1)` is not a string.  To set `Claimants` to an empty string instead, you can add `If`:

```
Dim Claimants As String = If(TryCast(myParams(1).Value, String), "")
```